# Nesting components in Angular4 (RC5)

Tags: angular, deprecated, angular2-directives, angular-components, angular-rc5

Getting into Angular and watching an outdated tutorial which is in fact for Angular2 (y, I know).

**Angular4:**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent , MyChildComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Seems that this is how you nest components now but isn't there a way to do it how it was done (or similarly) in Angular 2? As in you could import it in the now-deprecated 'directives' property DIRECTLY IN YOUR ROOT COMPONENT (found this really convenient for fast development).

**Angular2:**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   directives: [MyChildComponent]
   template: '<div><ChildComponent></ChildComponent></div>'
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Edit: Here's the MyChildComponent declaration (still part of Angular2):

```
@Component({
   selector: 'ChildComponent',
   template: '<h2>Child component</h2>'
})
export class MyChildComponent {}
```

Note: Omitted the import declarations

Comment: you are defining it as `directive` inside your component. How you can have same class for directive and component?

Comment: not the same. MyChildComponent's declaration is not up here. I'm gonna update it to avoid confusion. This isn't a "not working" type of question. just wondering if they have something else instead of "directives" (was present in Angular 2, now it's deprecated) keyword in Angular 4.

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point (I lost track of the different versions popping up daily a long time ago) they made the switch to module-based design and essentially did away with the `directives` overnight.

In order to use your components anywhere, you just need the `declarations: [...]` part in the module populated with your components in that module.

After that, you don't need the `directives` portion in the components at all.

In short:

- Any components listed in the `declarations` section of a module will make those components available to all other components *of that module*.
- Any components listed in the `exports` section of a module will make those components available to any other module that `imports` that module.

Comment: way better to have them there. much easier to scale and maintain. thanks for the answer